# How to edit an existing excel file in JS using SheetJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, sheetjs

I'm trying to create a little web-application that would interact with an excel file on client side.
Basically I need it to insert in the file the input the user insert in it.

I imported the library sheetJS since my project would run mainly on Chrome, but I'm now stuck on a problem.

I can't find how to make my code editing the existing excel file and saving it onto the very same file.

This is what I got currently:

```
$('#input-excel').change(function(e)    //user choose which file to upload 
    {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
            reader.onload = function(e) 
            {
                    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
                    var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array'});
                    var htmlstr = XLSX.write(wb,{type:'binary',bookType:'html'});
                    var fSN = wb.SheetNames[0];
                    var ws = wb.Sheets[fSN];
                   
                    if(!ws["E5"]) ws["E5"] = {};
                        ws["E5"].t = "s";
                     ws["E5"].v = $("#difference").val();

                    
                     XLSX.writeFile(wb, "test.xlsx");
            }
    });
```

It imports the file user indicates, insert the data in E5 but than saves on a new file, losing all formatting and formulas from the original file.

I know this might be a noob question, but do you know how could I edit this in order to have amendments done on the original file?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can't handle it with the community edition. https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/2266#issuecomment-917849147

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: Hi Robert, as far as I know there's not. At that time I opened the issue linked by NoobTW on GitHub and was told this is not possible. I haven't further checked as for my purposes  the community feature was still fine; however if it's crucial for your project I guess you should either go for the pro build or code the thing from scratch by yourself